# Only able to echo the first row of my available search tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to make a search bar using [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) and I'm echoing my rows into the availableTags. However I'm only getting the first row from my database. I know that I should use a `while` loop but I'm not sure where to place it. I've tried multiple times but I can't get it to do both.

```html
<?php 
  require_once 'config.php';
  require_once 'session.php';
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $query = "SELECT `user_id`, `username`, `leeftijd`, `email` FROM `users` ";
  $resultaat = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat);    
  var_dump($row);                      
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jqueryui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat)){ ?>
      $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>",
          "<?php echo $row['username'];?>",
          "<?php echo $row['leeftijd'];?>",

          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];

        $("#tags").autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });
      });
    <?php } ?>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the `while` loop around the values you echo in to the JS array

Comment: Do u mean in the var availableTags?

Comment: What does `echo mysqli_num_rows($resultaat);` give you?

Comment: It gives 2 back.

Comment: @citrical So it's correct. One you already got from initial 2 lines of `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat);    
  var_dump($row);` and another one from the while loop. Note that if you use `mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat);` even once, it automatically moves the cursor to the next row internally.

Comment: Put  `<?php mysqli_data_seek($resultaat, 0); ?>` before while loop and check results.

Comment: But how am i supposed to get the while loop in the Javascript without it canceling out the other row.

Comment: How do i check?

Comment: @citrical Do this `<?php mysqli_data_seek($resultaat, 0); ?>` before the while loop and check like bharat said.

Comment: But how am i supposed to check?

Comment: @vivek_23 I did this and it let me search if i remove the ! it wouldn't let me search and it doesn't let me echo with and withou the !. `<?php if(!mysqli_data_seek($resultaat, 0)){
      echo "hallo"; }?>`

Comment: @citrical Why do you want to echo anything there?

Comment: @bharatparmar Thank you I think I've figured it out, I was confused with if the while and mysqli_data_seek was supposed to be in the var or not. It now works properly and can display both rows. I dont know if It's useful but I'll paste my code underneath.

Comment: @vivek_23 Thank you I think I've figured it out, I was confused with if the while and mysqli_data_seek was supposed to be in the var or not. It now works properly and can display both rows. I dont know if It's useful but I'll paste my code underneath.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you I think I've figured it out, I was confused with if the while and mysqli_data_seek was supposed to be in the var or not. It now works properly and can display both rows. I dont know if It's useful but I'll paste my code underneath.

Comment: @citrical If my code works, upvoted my comment. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Add while loop like this:

```
while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat))
{  
  var_dump($row); 
}
```

In javascript you can use while like this:

```
var availableTags = [
  <?php while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat)){?>
    "<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>",
    "<?php echo $row['username'];?>",
    "<?php echo $row['leeftijd'];?>",
 <?php } ?>
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
```

Comment: I've done that but that only var dumps both rows, it doesn't echo both rows in the function.

Comment: I don't understand where i should put the while in the javascript part though.

Comment: But that only gives me the second row.

Answer (score 0):

It now works correctly, thank you everyone.

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'session.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$query = "SELECT `user_id`, `username`, `leeftijd`, `email` FROM `users` ";
                    $resultaat = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
                     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat);    
                      var_dump($row);
                      echo mysqli_num_rows($resultaat);



?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [    
      <?php !mysqli_data_seek($resultaat, 0)?>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultaat)){ ?>   
      "<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>",
      "<?php echo $row['username'];?>",
      "<?php echo $row['leeftijd'];?>",
      "<?php echo $row['email'];?>",
<?php } ?>
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    }); 
  } );

  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```